# Controling line inside circle

Tags: vb.net, winforms

What I want to do:

Lets say that I'm **holding** with the mouse the line:

[image]

When I'm moving the line around,the line not outing from the circle range.

What I don't want to do:

[image]

As you see, the line is outing from the circle range.

I want to draw the line and keep him inside my circle **when** I'm holding him with the mouse.

How can i do something like picture1?

This is the code:

```
Dim g As Graphics
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    Dim pt As New Drawing.Point
    pt.X = e.X
    pt.Y = e.Y
    g = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim myPen = New Pen(Color.Red)
    myPen.Width = 1
    g.Clear(Color.White)
    g.DrawLine(myPen, 100, 100, pt.X, pt.Y)

End Sub
```

Comment: If I got it right, you would like to "snap" one side of your line to the nearest point on the circle? Can you post some code you got so far?

Comment: yes, i want to keep my line inside the circel.

Comment: Should the line should always follow the clockwise path from 12h to 12h? If you only need the closest point on the circle then this thread might be helpful: [How to find a point on a circle closest to a given point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300871/best-way-to-find-a-point-on-a-circle-closest-to-a-given-point). But this solution might make the line jump around.

Comment: if you find other way, tell me =).

Comment: What is the purpose? Some sort of gesture recognition? Is it a game?

Comment: animation program like "pivot" (control stikman)

Comment: http://www.stickpage.com/stickanimatorgame.shtml