# Creating a point that follows touch/mouse input, but remains on a fixed distance from another stationary point

Tags: java, math, libgdx

I want to create a stationary point in the middle of the screen and when the user touches and drags on the screen it should create another point that will follow the users input but will always stay on a fixed distance from the other stationary point. I can easily make it so that the game tells me when the 2nd point is on that exact distance while dragging it around.

```
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    setPosition(a, b);
    return true;
}
```

So basically I want to know how to set the a (x-coordinate) and b (y-coordinate) correctly.
Also I'm not sure if this is more of a mathematical problem or does libgdx (or java for that matter) have any nifty things I could use?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a convoluted way of asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300871/best-way-to-find-a-point-on-a-circle-closest-to-a-given-point; there is a nice and concise answer for you there.

Comment: Yeah, this solves it. English isn't my main language so I struggled to find the right words for my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For the Libgdx-specific support, there isn't much that I know of.  That said I think you can use a [`Vector2`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html) then normalize it ([`Vector2.nor()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#nor%28%29)) then multiply it by your "fixed distance" ([`Vector2d.mul()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#mul%28float%29))

```
private final Vector2 perimiterPoint = new Vector2();
private float centerX = ...;
private float centerY = ...;
private float radius = ...; // The "fixed distance" radius of your circle.

public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    perimiterPoint.set(x - centerX, y - centerY).nor().mul(circleRadius)
    setPosition(perimiterPoint.x, perimiterPoint.y);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It works only if I had the static point at (0,0) on the screen and I'm encountering some problems with that, because I'm pretty much a newbie programmer and still have a lot of stuff to figure out, but the algorithm that the guy in the comments listed works just fine for now.

Comment: If you're using libgdx scene2d Actors beware of the difference between "screen space", "stage space" , and "actor space" (the x,y values are relative to one of those and can be transformed among them).