# Logic for calculating distance between points

Tags: python

Am trying to find the distance between a point [x1, y1] and the nearest point on the circle centered at [c1, c2] with radius 2?
I devised the following equation for this

```
sqrt((p[0] - c[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - c[1]) ** 2)
```

But the answer it returns an answer which seems to be wrong...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your formula calculates the distance to the center of the circle.  Subtract the radius, and take the absolute value.

```
radius = 2
abs(sqrt((p[0] - c[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - c[1]) ** 2) - radius)
```

**Note:** Yes, this will work for points on or inside the circle.

Comment: What is the name of this formula?

Comment: @orlybg: I am not aware of any name.  I created it from the Euclidean distance metric.

Answer (score 0):

That will give you the distance between the point and the *centre* of the circle, not the nearest point on the circumference

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300871/2065121) for an algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to minimize the distance to a point on the circumference, so I would use some calculus optimization. The solution is (x, y) below.

```
f(x, y) = (x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 // the distance formula

(x - c1)^2 + (y - c2)^2 = 2 ^ 2 = 4 // the equation of the circle
```